# How to know duration of any media file

Tags: android

My application shows list of media(audio and Video) files in the sdcard along with file size,mime type. I now want to add total duration of the media file in the every list item.
I tried fetching the duration using following code

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION };
 Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
 int column_index
  = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION);
```

but `MediaStore` returns correct duration only if the media is played before, if not it returns 0. I cannot use `videoview.getDuration` since I don't want to play the video. 
I want your help to know if I am making any mistake in above code or if there is any other way to fetch duration **without playing it first**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use MediaMetadataRetriever to read the duration from the file. But using this class will require your project to be at least API level 10 (Android 2.3.3).

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I will have a look at this class. Will update this thread with result.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I could get the duration of a video file using MediaMetaDataRetriever. My app is designed for API Level 10 and up so this API comes in handy.

Comment: Glad to know I could help, and that it didn't mess with your application's device compatibility.